# Twig filter only avialable to custom extended function

Tags: twig

Is there any way to create a Twig filter that can only be used with specific function but nothing else?

For examples lets say i have custom function collection() and when i apply "sort" filter to it it'll use the filter function "sort" in that extended class not the default twig "sort" filter?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to use a built-in filter or a custom filter according to an input type.

My suggestion is to create a custom `my_sort` filter that will have a different behaviour according to your needs.

- If your variable is an instance of Colleciton, then you use a `sort()` method
- Else, you copy the behaviour of default `sort` filter.

Something like:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
            'my_sort' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'my_sort'),
    );
}

public function my_sort($stuff)
{
    if (is_array($stuff))
    {
        sort($stuff);
    }
    else if ((is_object($stuff)) && ($stuff instanceof Collection))
    {
        $stuff->sort();
    }
}
```